# Ubuntu 18.04 reboots randomly

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 for several months, maybe a year. But since last July my ubuntu started to reboot randomly.

The command `last reboot` outputs the following

```
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug 11 14:32   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug 11 12:44   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug 11 12:39   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug 11 12:01   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sat Aug 10 12:59 - 20:47  (07:48)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Fri Aug  9 22:35 - 23:24  (00:49)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Wed Aug  7 19:04 - 23:52  (04:47)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Tue Aug  6 18:55 - 01:59  (07:04)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Mon Aug  5 20:11 - 00:17  (04:06)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug  4 12:33 - 00:22  (11:48)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sun Aug  4 12:02 - 00:22  (12:19)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Sat Aug  3 01:13 - 02:01  (00:48)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-55-generi Fri Aug  2 22:23 - 02:01  (03:38)
```

I thought it was one of my startup applications or any google chrome extensions doing weird things. I noticed that my computer rebooted when watching youtube videos or while idle after startup.I have disabled all my startup applications and all the chrome extensions I installed recently; I left the extensions I've since since forever. However my laptop keeps rebooting.

I also use spacemacs in server mode I disabled it thinking it can be due to intensive use. It didn't solve my issue.

I have my installation up-to-date.

It can be the fans, but Which log do I check? Also, I don't think the fans are the problem because my laptop doesn't reboot so often.

Any help to troubleshoot this will be appreciated. Which logs should I look into?